# Trail Running translation

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, sport

I've seen the term "trail running" translated as "course à pied" and "course de sentir".
I appreciate one may be grammatically correct and the other a colloquialism, or something similar.

As far as I can tell "course à pied" transliterates as "race of feet" whereas "course de sentir" is "race of feel(ing)".

Are both terms correct or interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Course à pied" is just a generic term for running, even though the literal translation might seem a bit funny.

I have never heard the term "course de sentir", which doesn't really mean anything, but I think what you meant instead is "course de sentier", which would be a literal translation of trail running, a trail (in the woods) being a sentier (dans la forêt).

The French [Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_(course_%C3%A0_pied)) refers to it as "trail", "course nature" ou plus rarement "course en sentier".

Comment: Must have been a missspelling then. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistranslating *course **à pied***.

"Race of feet" would be *course **de** pieds* which is equally non-sensical in French.

*À pied* litteraly means *by feet*, i.e. using our own feet as "transportation method", just like we say ***à vélo***, **à cheval**, or **en voiture**.

We say *course cycliste, hippique, automobile* for the former, and we might say ***course pédestre*** for *course à pied*, but the latter is much more common.

*Course de sentier* is not idiomatic.

Comment: Yes of course! "By" rather than "of", schoolboy error on my part there! Thanks for highlighting this.

Answer (score 1):

> [Course en sentier](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26545140) : « Course à pied se pratiquant sur des
>   sentiers balisés. » (GDT)
>   [Course de pleine nature](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=trail%20running&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) : «
>   Course d'endurance en terrain naturel et varié, dans laquelle les
>   concurrents enchaînent des difficultés pouvant imposer une alternance
>   de marche et de course. » (Franceterme ; GDT)